# How to reconstruct signature from R, s?

Tags: transactions, signature

I'm implementing EddSA, and already generate verified R, s for signature.

However, when sending tx using js, the signature verification fails.

The way to generate signature from R, s:

```
sig = new byte[64]
sig[0:32] = R
sig[32:64] = s
```

The way to submit a tx:

```
tx.addSignature(signerPublickey, Buffer.from(sig));
txHash = await connection.sendRawTransaction(tx.serialize()); // signature verification fails.
```

Any thought?

Comment: Signature verification can fail for a multitude of reasons, not just incorrect R and s params. Two things to consider:


- Does the number of signatures in the message header match the number of actual signatures including your manually added sig? (I'd assume yes since you're using `addSignature` but can't hurt to double check)


- Does the index at which your adding your sig match the index of the belonging public key in account addresses array of your transaction?

Comment: Let me know if either of these were the problem and I will add it as an answer. If not, please provide an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @ElliotSolskjaer Thanks for the reply. The transaction is simply transferring SOL from A to B. So, just A's signature is needed, right? I guess in this case, there is no need for index.